# Can I be let go for sharing an employer's Facebook post?

Tags: termination

So my job was threatened in Tennessee for reposting a facebook post my employer posted about us hiring for some positions.

I posted it and a former employee put  emoji and they threatened my job. Can I be terminated for that?

Comment: Question: Did you add any context to the FB Post? If you just re-posted a Hiring advert, putting aside At-Will state provisions - it would be hard for an Employer to hold you responsible for the actions of a 3rd party.

Comment: What does the facebook post say ?

Comment: What is TN? An abbreviation of two letters can be anything nowadays without context.

Comment: It sounds like there are important facts being left out. Do you understand exactly what they are unhappy about? If not, have you asked for help understanding it? If you do understand but simply disagree, continuing to fight it is likely to be a Career Limiting Move even if they don't actually invite you to leave.

Comment: My guess is the they are unhappy that the OP didn't remove the  emoji. Although someone else posted it, the OP presumably had the power to either remove the comment or the whole post.

Comment: What does "my job was threatened" even mean? Did somebody with the authority to fire you talk to you? If so, what exactly did they say?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming by "TN", you mean the state of Tennessee, United States (please remember this is an international site) then yes, as a "right to work" state you can be terminated for any reason or none (other than discrimination on the grounds of race, etc).

Comment: Maybe unless you are in the 25% of US employees that have some form of employment contract...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere What makes you say that?

Comment: Most rational companies would be quite happy for their employees to pass on the fact the company is hiring to their network. Weird.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I should have said "not at-will" rather than "have some form of employment contract"

Comment: @JoeStrazzere That may be so, but it remains that 25% of of US employees are not at-will. Which means they cannot be spuriously fired (this is the definition of at-will as you know). So I'm guessing there are a lot of union-bargained agreements and personal contracts that exist to make this so (even if you don't work in an industry where you have come across them).